# How to configure Coldfusion 10 CFLDAP to use TLS instead of SSL2

Tags: ssl, ldap, tls, coldfusion, poodle

We are using CFLDAP to authenticate users from a remote system. The remote system has now shut down SSL 2 and 3 due to the POODLE issue. Is there a way to configure either Coldfusion or Tomcat to use TLS as the outgoing connection?

Comment: The underlying java *should* support TLSv1 for the connection.  If I remember correctly, the exceptions thrown by cfldap are completely unhelpful for determining why the connection failed; can you set up wireshark on a system with the problem and capture the connection handshake to look at what it's doing?

Comment: It might also make a difference depending on whether CF is running on Windows or Linux.

Comment: We are running on Windows. We're in the process of securing IIS but that is for the incoming connections. CFLDAP is an outgoing connection.

Comment: Have you tried disabling SSL2 and 3 via the registry?  I know it's an outgoing connection, but...  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3009008.aspx

Comment: What is the underlying Java version James? I may have an ansewr for you.

Comment: Those have been disabled for both SSL2 and 3. Server entries have "DisabledByDefault" set to 1 and "Enabled" set to 0. Client entries have only "DisabledByDefault" set to 1.

Comment: The server I'm testing on has Java 6 (jre 1.6.0_29)